# Trying to laucnh Cassandra on a sever and I get an error

Tags: tomcat, cassandra

I'm trying to launch cassandra on my server (Linux based and using tomcat) and I'm getting the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
The size of the object heap + VM data exceeds the maximum representable size
```

My server only has 512MB of RAM, and I'm using the following config for catalina:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms128m -Xmx384m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Try http://zefonseca.com/blogs/zen/solved-jvm-problem-apache-cassandra-fails-to-start-up/ for a solution for a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cassandra conf directory you have a cassandra-env.sh file
You should update there the heap definition values

```
#MAX_HEAP_SIZE="4G"
#HEAP_NEWSIZE="800M"
```

Remove the remark and put your sizes there